# what is the solution of array length problem

Tags: c#, arrays, size

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G952g.png)

As you see in the image, the length of all the arrays is [4], but even when I enter two values to store in the array this message appears, how is that possible and the array size is 4??!!

***note: numbers[] array Length is [5]***

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this is the main array to save user numbers
        string[] numbers = new string[5];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 phone numbers");

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            // user input
            numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
            phoneNumbers(numbers);
    }

  
    public static void phoneNumbers(string[] numbers)
    {

        

        // 4 arrays, for each array will store numbers if it belongs to STC,MOBILY,ZAIN or invaild 
        string[] stcNum = new string[4];
        string[] mobilyNum = new string[4];
        string[] zainNum = new string[4];
        string[] invaildNum = new string[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {

            // an if statment to check if the number belong to STC, if yes, store it in STC array
            if (numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("050") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("055"))
            {
                stcNum[i] = numbers[i];
            }

            // an if statment to check if the number belong to Mobily, if yes, store it in Mobily array
            else if (numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("056") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("054"))
            {
                mobilyNum[i] = numbers[i];
            }

            // an if statment to check if the number belong to Zain, if yes, store it in Zain array
            else if (numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("053") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("059"))
            {
                zainNum[i] = numbers[i];
            }

            // an if statment to check if the number is invalid, if yes, store it in invaild array
            else if (!(numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("050") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("055") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("056") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("054") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("053") || numbers[i].Substring(0, 3).Equals("059")))
            {
                invaildNum[i] = numbers[i];
            }

        }
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere I did , sorry that's my first time.

Comment: `numbers` is 5 long. The others are 4. - Hint: Never use an array when you can use a List<T> !

Comment: You may find OOP useful: creating dedicated type to hold properties of object is less prone to mistakes than using separate array and mapping them by index.

Comment: I have a hunch that you still believe there is some sort of mystery, but your loop tries to access the 5th element of arrays that are only 4 elements long.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `string[] stcNum = new string[4];` with `List<string> stcNum = new List<string>();` and `stcNum[i] = numbers[i];` with `stcNum.Add(numbers[i]);` etc.

Also you need to check if entered phone number is longer than 2 characters, otherwise you code will crush again.